# cant create class name for span in regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, typescript

when i try to create class name for span element, getting error.

```
 var regex = new RegExp("(" + input + ")", "im");
 str = str.replace(regex, ("<span class="name">$1</span>"));
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the **"** character in replace

```
var input = 'i';
var str = 'kaixo';
var pattern = new RegExp("(" + input + ")", "gim");
str = str.replace(pattern, ("<span class=\"target\">$1</span>"));

console.log(str);
```

Output:

```
ka<span class="target">i</span>xo
```